# Backspacing with vim

Tags: vim

I realize that the "command" for erasing a letter is x, but if you're seriously just erasing like 3-5 letters, is it really beneficial at all to press `ESC + hhhhh + xxxxx`?

In vim, is there any reason we can't use the backspace?

Comment: Backspace works fine for me.

Comment: That depends on what is the context, without any more info `Esc + 4Xx` would do the same. If you give a sample of the text maybe we could see if there is a shorter way.

Comment: Is this question about what the point of the x command is, or about how to actually use the backspace key in vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your your typing sequence starts with `<Esc>` I assume you are in *insert* mode, right? If so, you can type `<C-w>` to delete the word on the left of the cursor without leaving *insert* mode.

Hitting `<bs>` works in *insert* mode as well for single characters, there's no real need to get out of it if you only need to delete a few of the characters you just typed.

`x` is "the" command to erase a letter in *normal* mode but it only works alone (`x`) or with a count (`5x`), same for `X`. There are many situations where you need to act on a whole word or two, or what's between a pair of parenthesis, or until a specific pattern forward, or until and including a specific letter backward… In such situations, you should use `d` in combination with motions.

Comment: And then there's '<C-o>' in _insert_ mode, which lets you enter a single _normal_ mode command without really leaving.

Answer (score 2):

In command mode, Backspace is used to move cursor to left. If you want to use it as expected, use following command in command mode:

```
:nnoremap <bs> X
```

Add it in your `.vimrc` file if you want permanent change.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ESC hhhhh xxxxx`, try `d5h`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the mapping Sachin Shekhar suggested or do it "the Vi way", but there is in my opinion a better way:

The `backspace` setting controls how the Backspace key works. Putting this in your .vimrc makes the Backspace key work the way most people expect:

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Do `:h 'backspace` for more information.